# Button Gets Hidden when clicked and results are shown in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to create an application that can show output of shell commands. It looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6web.png

When i click the ping Button with some shell command as input eg(ls /proc) the output of the command  overwrites the ping button.(i.e the ping button becomes invisible)

Mainxml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_ip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Enter ip"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
            android:autofillHints="None" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_ping"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ping"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:id="@+id/scrollview_pingresult"
            tools:ignore="ExtraText">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_pingresult"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView tv_result = findViewById(R.id.textview_pingresult);
        final EditText et_ip = findViewById(R.id.edittext_ip);
        final Button btn_ping = findViewById(R.id.button_ping);


        btn_ping.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    String cmd = et_ip.getText().toString();
                    PingIp.executecmd(cmd, tv_result);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the `btn_ping` after a click, try setting visibility gone like this

```
btn_ping.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    String cmd = et_ip.getText().toString();
                    PingIp.executecmd(cmd, tv_result);
                    //here is where you hide the button
                    btn_ping.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```